# Joint distribution of two Gaussian variables

Tags: probability, integration, continuity, normal-distribution

I have some questions concerning gaussian variables.

Suppose I have two gaussians RV $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that $\text{corr}(g_1, g_2)=\rho$ .

$g_1$ and $g_2$ are not necessarly jointly gaussian, my questions are the following:

-Do we have an idea about the joint distribution of $(g_1,g_2)$ ? Can we write that $g_1 = \rho g_2 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z$ with $Z$ independant of $g_2$ or are we allowed to write it only if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are jointly gaussian?

Lot of thanks

Comment: Does it check out in the case $g_1=\pm g_2$, where the sign choice is independent of $g_2$?  (This is a simple example where $(g_1,g_2)$ are marginally Gaussian but not jointly Gaussian.  In this case $\rho=0$.)